# Save multiple data in database column from select multiple

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to save more than one university under one student. For html select I used

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" name="university">
  @foreach($districts as $row)
     <option value= {{$row->name}} > {{$row->name}} </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

This taking previously saved university. I am using district as university.

Controller->

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
         Seller_info::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'passport' => $request['passport'],
            'phone_number' => $request['phone_number'],
            'address' => $request['address'],
            'dateofbirth' => $request['dateofbirth'],
            'ielts' => $request['ielts'],
            'openingcharge' => $request['openingcharge'],
            'serviceCharge' => $request['serviceCharge'],
            'applydate' => $request['applydate'],
            'visaStatus'=> $request['visaStatus'],
            'country' => $request['country'],
            'university'=> $request['university'],
           
        ]);
        return back();
    }
```

This is saving the students. This is a mishmash code I am sorry about that. I am working on a different for fast learning. Here I am using seller_info as student.

The data is is saving university but only one university in the database. I tried to use for loop in case of storing. But could not able to implement it properly.

My table file->

```
Schema::create('seller_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('passport')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('dateofbirth')->nullable();
            $table->string('ielts')->nullable();
            $table->string('openingcharge')->nullable();
            $table->string('serviceCharge')->nullable();
            $table->string('applydate')->nullable();
            $table->string('visaStatus')->nullable();
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('university')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

And model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'passport', 'phone_number','address','dateofbirth','ielts', 'openingcharge','serviceCharge','applydate',
        'visaStatus','country','university'

    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store multiple university data for one student first of all you need 3 table, students(so your Seller Info), universities and seller_info_university(will be pivot table),

seller_info_university Migration must be like;

```
Schema::create('seller_info_university', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('seller_info_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('university_id')->unsigned();
});
```

Add this code your SellerInfo Model;

```
public function universities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(University::class); // Your University model
}
```

Add this code your University Model;

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(SellerInfo::class); // Your Student(SellerInfo) model
}
```

In your Controller try this

```
$student = Seller_info::create([
    'name' => $request['name'],
    'email' => $request['email'],
    'passport' => $request['passport'],
    'phone_number' => $request['phone_number'],
    'address' => $request['address'],
    'dateofbirth' => $request['dateofbirth'],
    'ielts' => $request['ielts'],
    'openingcharge' => $request['openingcharge'],
    'serviceCharge' => $request['serviceCharge'],
    'applydate' => $request['applydate'],
    'visaStatus'=> $request['visaStatus'],
    'country' => $request['country'],
    // 'university'=> $request['university'], you dont need there anymore  
    ]);

    $student->universities()->attach($request['universities']); // You can use attach(), detach() or sync() functions, you can search in Laravel Documentation

    return back();
```

And View;

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" name="universities[]">
  @foreach($districts as $row)
     <option value= {{$row->name}} > {{$row->name}} </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Specially for the comments. It helped me to understand more.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear if i helped for you